Best URL structure for a "Product reviews by rating" feature
I run a board game media website (WordPress) which publishes product reviews, each of which include a numeric rating.
https://www.meeplemountain.com/

Currently my URL structure is as follows:
https://www.meeplemountain.com/reviews/
https://www.meeplemountain.com/reviews/rock-hard-1977/
https://www.meeplemountain.com/reviews/everdell-duo/
etc.

I'd like to add a feature which aggregates reviews by their rating so that we can link to it. My question is what might be the best URL structure for search engine and users to understand. Here's a few possibilities, but I'm open to suggestions.
https://www.meeplemountain.com/reviews/by-rating/4-stars
https://www.meeplemountain.com/reviews-by-rating/1-stars
https://www.meeplemountain.com/board-game-reviews-by-rating/4-stars
https://www.meeplemountain.com/ratings/4-stars

Keep in mind that WordPress "owns" the reviews endpoint and child URLs so that would be more challenging. I'm leaning towards the second one "reviews-by-rating" because it's not only descriptive, but it's not already in use, which should make it easier for me to code against.
I'd love to hear your input, thanks.
